ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.7.1 has origin set to null in request header or not found (but expected origin is set to domain url)
An ASP.NET MVC web app on .NET 4.7.1, when accessed in Chrome browser, the request header has no origin. The request header should have origin set to domain name.
When I access first time, it redirect to login page for authentication, and both request does not have origin in their request header.
I have the setting in my web.config that set Content-Security-Policy for default-src, object-src, connect-src, form-action, frame-ancestors, img-src, style-src, script-src, font-src, etc
Whatever content url in my app also has no origin or it is set to null.
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
            <remove name="X-AspNetMvc-Version" />
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
            <add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
            <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
            <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer" />
            <add name="X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies" value="none" />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; 
            object-src 'self'; 
            connect-src 'self' https://localhost:4111 ; 
            form-action 'self'; 
            frame-ancestors 'none'; 
            img-src 'self' https://*.bing.com https://*.virtualearth.net data:; 
            style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  ; 
            script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ; 
            font-src 'self'  data:;" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

Please advise what should I do to have origin set to domain name.
The initial request to home page as well as login and subsequent may content like css , js etc has no origin in the request header but this subsequent request https://xyz.visualstudio.com/v2/track has origin set to domain url
Why other request at initial stage does not have any value for origin?
What can I do?
